# Deleting one of each chosen elements in a list containing duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to delete one of each (and not all) selected element in a list containing duplicates.

For example i have the list: $\{1,1,1,2,2,3\}$ and i want to delete $\{1,3\}$ so the leftover should be $\{1,1,2,2\}$ (and not $\{2,2\}$).

I tried working with $DeleteCases$ and $Alternatives$, but could only delete all elements which match the pattern:

```
r={1,1,1,2,2,3}; 
del={1,3};
DeleteCases[r, Alternatives @@ del]
```

Little side question: Is there a better way for adding elements than

```
add={4,5};  
Flatten[Append[r, add]]
```

?

Thanks a lot,
kon

Comment: For your little question, `Flatten[{r,add}]`, or `AppendTo[r,add]` or `Join[r,add]` I think should all work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the fourth argument of `DeleteCases` to specify how many instances of a case to delete:

```
dcF = Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &, ##] &;

r = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3};

dcF[r, {1, 3}]
(* {1, 1, 2, 2} *)

dcF[r, {1, 1}]
(* {1, 2, 2, 3} *)

dcF[{a, a, a, 2, 2, c}, {2, 2, 2, c, c, c}]
(* {a, a, a} *)
```

**Update:**

> *is it possible to return {0} when trying to delete more instances of a case then r contains*

```
delF[r_, del_] := If[Min[Count[r, #1] - #2 & @@@ Tally[del]] < 0, {0},
                     Fold[DeleteCases[##, 1, 1] &, r, del]]
delF[{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2}]
(* {1, 3} *)
delF[{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 2}]
(* {0} *)
```

Comment: is it possible to return {0} when trying to delete more instances of a case then r contains?

Comment: @kon, please see the update.

Comment: @kguler Ha! I forgot to check the docs on `DeleteCases` itself.

Comment: @tkott,  third/fourth optional arguments  are easy to forget:)  When i find myself wishing a certain function handled a  new/seemingly-new case i first check the docs for alternative signatures.

Comment: @kguler it works fine, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach this is:

```
delParts = First /@ (Position[r, #] & /@ del)
```

Then

```
Delete[r, delParts]
```

I.e., find the position of all the pieces you want, separated into groups, take the first part of each group, and delete there.

Comment: I just realised it does not work when trying to delete two of the same element: eg.: del={1,1}

Comment: Could it also return {0} when you try to delete more elements than r contains? Like del={3,3}?

Answer (score 1):

Using pattern matching:

```
r = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3};
del = {1, 3};

Fold[Replace, r, {{s___, #, e___} -> {s, e}} & /@ del]
```

> `{1, 1, 2, 2}`